# Firebird SELECT-Statement as criteria for UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-update, firebird, firebird2.5

I want to UPDATE some attribute of exactly that result rows that I get with this statement:

```
select adr.lkz, adr.adressnr, adr.kundennr, adr.vertreter1 as VERTRETERNR, adr.kurzname, ans.name as ANSPRECHPARTNER, ans.telefon, adr.plz, adr.ort from ans
left join adr rt on ans.id = rt.id
left join adr on adr.adressnr = ans.adressnr
left join vet on adr.vertreter1 = vet.vertreternr
 where adr.plz similar to '26%' or adr.plz similar to '27%' or adr.plz similar to '28%' or adr.plz similar to '29%' or adr.plz similar to '30%' or adr.plz similar to '31%'
```

How can I put that result set as an criteria for the UPDATE-statement?

Comment: Firebird has positioned updates, although that would need some work as you are selecting from more than one table. Other solutions could include using `EXECUTE BLOCK` and iterating over the result and firing of updates one by one.

Comment: Does that mean, that I cannot put everything in one single statement?
I also read about Firebird would not support JOINs in UPDATE-statements.
("MS SQL 7 and above supports modification on joins (update, delete, insert). Firebird has no such syntax.", http://firebirdsql.org/manual/migration-mssql-syntax.html)

Comment: It depends how or what you want to update and I think your question lacks information to give a real answer. That said, you might want to look at [`merge`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-merge.html).